# searching for substring in select options without values

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to search for a specific substring in text retrieved from options that are populated from mysql, how do i return the text value of the option selected so that i can search for my substring.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("borrowitem").change(function() {
    $("#borrowitem option:selected").text();
    var optionValue = $(this).text;
    if (optionValue == "non-consumable") {
      $("#showtime").hide();
    } else {
      $("#showtime").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control input-lg borrowitem" name="borrowitem[]" required="required" id="borrowitem"><option></option></select>
```

Comment: so do you want the selected text madam ?

Comment: You're selector is all wrong  `$("borrowitem")` and `$( "#borrowitem option:selected" )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are there two two $("#showtime").hide(); & not a show() in the if else..

anyways here is code you had missed the ID selector #

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#borrowitem").change(function(){
       var optionValue=  $( "#borrowitem option:selected" ).val();   
           console.log(optionValue);
            if(optionValue == "non-consumable") {
                    $("#showtime").hide();
                }
    else{
                    $("#showtime").show();
                }
        });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>


<select class="form-control input-lg borrowitem" name="borrowitem[]" required="required" id="borrowitem">
  <option value="non-consumable">carrot</option>
  <option value="non-consumable">potato</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="non-consumable">apple</option>
</select>
  
  <br/><hr/><br/>
  
  <div id="showtime">SHow TIME</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks thanks for your answer,though i used Artisticphoenix's code and its done exactly what i needed it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Look for selected value as `$(this).val() === 'non-consumable'` inside the change event. For instance

```js
$('#borrowitem').change(function () {
  console.log($(this).val() === 'non-consumable');
});
```

```html
<select id="borrowitem">
  <option>non-consumable</option>
  <option>consumable</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If it's a multiple select, change the condition to

```
$(this).val().indexOf('non-consumable') !== -1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this example code

you pass `id with # in onchange event` and write `onchange as .on("change",function())` and get selected using `$("#borrowitem option:selected").text()`  so it will work

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#borrowitem").on("change", function() {
    // alert($("#borrowitem option:selected").text());
    var optionValue = $("#borrowitem option:selected").text();
    //alert(optionValue);
    if (optionValue == "non-consumable") {
      $("#showtime").hide();
    } else {
      $("#showtime").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control input-lg borrowitem" name="borrowitem[]" required="required" id="borrowitem"><option>test</option>
<option>non-consumable</option></select>

<span id="showtime">hello</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

Something the others missed is that you have to check when the page loads what the state of the initial showtime element should be.  For example: we could load it pre-hidden with `non-consumable` as the selected option, or we could load it shown with the selected option `consumable`.

One big reason we may need to do that is for a "sticky" form. Which is a form that retains it's value after a submission attempt.

To do that, all we need to do is "functionize" the action we want to take.  Basically just create a function to do it, then call it from the event handler and from the `onReady` event when the page is ready.  Instead of placing it directly in the event handler.

So Orange is `consumable` and then green is `non-consumable`. I wanted something visible so I added the `orange` box for the `showtime`. Then I wrapped that in a green box to hold the place open when it's hidden.  Mainly this was to keep the select element from jumping around when the box was hidden, but I also liked the contrast.

Another thing most ( all ) of them missed is this:

> so that i can search for my substring

see below for explanation

```js
   (function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){

     /* set state of showtime */
     function setShowtimeState ()
     {
         var text = $('#borrowitem').find('option:selected').text();
         var Regx = new RegExp(/\bnon\-consumable\b/, 'i'); //case insensitive

         if( Regx.test(text) )
             $('#showtime').hide();
         else
             $('#showtime').show();
      }

       //call on change of the select element
      $('#borrowitem').change(setShowtimeState );

      //call on ready to set the initial state
      setShowtimeState ();
  });
   })(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <div id="showtime-wrapper" style="margin-bottom: 5px;width:50px;height:50px;background:green; border: 1px solid black;">
     <div id="showtime" style="width:100%;height:100%;background:orange;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<select class="form-control input-lg borrowitem" name="borrowitem[]" required="required" id="borrowitem">
     <option>- pick an option - </option>
     <option>non-consumable</option>
     <option>consumable</option>
     <option>this is non-consumable</option>
     <option>this is consumable</option>
     <option>Case Insensitive NON-Consumable</option>
</select>
```

**REGx**

I used a Regular Expression to match the sub-string.  This is a bit complex if you never messed with them but it's the best way to match.  I will walk you through the pattern I used a bit:

```
/\bnon\-consumable\b/
```

So to break this down for you

- the `/` is called the delimiter, its used to mark the start|end of the regx
- the `\b` matches a word boundary. For example if we use a `|` to mark the word boundaries for this string `|foobar| |is| |a| |word|`.  The purpose of that is if we look for the sub-string `foo`, we could match that in `foobar` but if we look for `\bfoo\b` it would not match because there is no word boundary between `foo` and `bar`.  This helps prevent false matches on sub-strings.
- the "letters" are just letters and match literally letter for letter
- then we have the closing delimter `/` that ends the Regx

The second argument of `new RegExp` is the flag, an I used the `i` flag for case-insensitive matching, you can omit it for case sensitive matches.

For more info  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

One thing I feel obligated to mention is you have the name of the select `borrowitem[]` with the array brackets.  Typically this is done for one of 2 reasons:

1. Pass multiple elements of this name to the server
2. Set the multiple flag for the select box and make it multi-select

Both of these would require some code changes.  But there is a 3rd option, you just did it, because.

Comment: thank you so much, and the borrowitem[] was multi-select i just didn't like it then neglected to change code, thanks though really appreciate it.